# Should we consider the velocity for the Congruence of two curves?

Tags: differential-geometry

For the arbitrary speed two curves $\alpha(t), \beta(t)$ defined by $t(\in \mathbb{R}) \to  \mathbb{R}^3$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined on the same real line (intervals))

Say the $V_\alpha, V_\beta$ are the speeds of the two curves respectively.
$\kappa_\alpha$ and $\kappa_\beta$ are the curvatures of the two curves.

$\tau_\alpha$ and $\tau_\beta$ are the torsions of the two curves.

According to my books, it said " If $V_\alpha = V_\beta$, $\kappa_\alpha =\kappa_\beta$ and $\vert \tau_\alpha \vert = \vert \tau_\beta\vert $ Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruence."

From here my question begins. I'm so curious about the inverse of the proposition Which means

" If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruence, Then  $V_\alpha = V_\beta$, $\kappa_\alpha =\kappa_\beta$ and $\vert \tau_\alpha \vert = \vert \tau_\beta\vert $  "

In my point of view, it is false statement. Though $V_\alpha \neq V_\beta$, If Well-defining the arc length functions respectively, We can make them to unit speed curves automatically, simultaneously! Therefore, We don't need to consider the velocity of them.

In short, The true statement is

"If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruence then  $\kappa_\alpha =\kappa_\beta$ and $\vert \tau_\alpha \vert = \vert \tau_\beta\vert $".

Are there any fallacy or misunderstood in my thought?

Comment: I assume $V_\alpha,V_\beta$ refer to the norm of the derivatives of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. My intuition tells me that the requirement for the speeds to be the same is so that we can actually compare the rest of the functions (curvature and torsion) with respect to the same parameter.

Comment: If the two curves congruence, $\beta = A(\alpha)+b$ for the orthonormal matrix A. (Remarking the isometry.) From here just calculate the norm of the $\beta'$. Then you can discover it is equal with the $\alpha'$. Hence we can deduce speeds are equal.  So the former is right, Not yours.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to clarify that you are both using the following definition of congruence: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruent as functions, meaning $\beta$ is the composition of a rigid movement with $\alpha$.

In general, I'd like to think about a slight generalization of this problem, where congruence is applied as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$.